# How to save login credentials in cookie in Angular 14

Tags: angular, laravel

I have a website in Angular 14 and Laravel 8.
I want to save login credentials, so user may not have to enter the login credentials every time.
How can i achieve this with Cookies?

Here is my login controller

```
public function login()

    {

        $this->request->validate([

            'email' => 'required|email',

            'password' => 'required'

        ]);

        $user = User::where('email', $this->request->email)->first();

        $user->tokens()->delete();

        if (! $user || ! Hash::check($this->request->password, $user->password)) {

            return R::SimpleError('The provided credentials are incorrect.');

        }
        if($user->active == 1){
            return R::SimpleError('Please contact support team!');
        }

        $token = $user->createToken($this->request->email)->plainTextToken;

        $user->remember_token = $token;

        $user->save();

        return R::Success($token, $user);

    }
```

Comment: By refreshing the token even with an expired one(with limits). saving the login credentials in cookies is a very bad idea

Comment: Please suggest the good one

Comment: when you catch an expired token response, refresh it https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#refreshing-tokens if you are using laravel passport

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CookieService** in Angular, here is example:

```
import { CookieService } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

 const expirationDate = new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7); 
this.cookieService.set('loginCredentials', `${this.request.email}:${this.request.password}`, expirationDate);
```

Comment: this function i need to put in component.ts or module.ts file in Angular?

Comment: yes this way...

Comment: i tried to put your code in login.component.ts, and my login page stopped working. I mean login form stopped showing. Any idea?